# LaTeX Error: Illegal characters in array with Dynamic OT table generator

Tags: tables, beamer, arrays

I get numerous error messages like "! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token ([): `c' used." regarding this code:

```
\begin{center} \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.2}
\scalebox{0.9}[0.9]{\begin{tabular}[t]{|llc||c|c|c|c:c|c|c:c|c|} \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c||}{\textipa{i$_{\mu}^{H}$}} & {*[--low]} & {Max-$\mu$} & {Lic-$\mu$} & {Max[--high]} & {Lic-H} & {Max-T} & {Max[+high]} & {Max[--low]} & \textit{H} \\[0.5ex]
        \hline  \multicolumn{3}{|c||}{Weights} & 9.0 & 5.0 & 4.0 & 3.0 & 3.0 & 2.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & \\
        \hline \hline & a. & \textipa{i$_{\mu}^{H}$} & -1 & & & & & & & & -9 \\
        \hline & b. & \textipa{$_{\mu}^{H}$} & & & -1 & & -1 & & -1 & -1 & -9 \\
        \hline \ding{43} & c. & \textipa{$_{\mu}$} & & & -1 & & & -1 & -1 & -1 & -8 \\
        \hline \end{tabular}} \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1} \end{center} \label{HG1}
```

It used to work two weeks ago, but then I needed to reinstall MiKTeX in order to be able to use beamer package. No idea why. The point is that now all my previous documents can't be compiled, with the same error message.

I appreciate any help!

Jelena

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: unrelated to the error, but only scale tables as  a last resort

Answer (score 3):

My freshly cleaned crystal ball says: Load the `arydshln` package after the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln} % Remove this line to recreate the error

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{|c:c|}
     1 & 2\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```